# Spring 22 testmethod GACK when assigning a PermissionSet to a newly-created user

Tags: failing-tests, permission-sets, gack

If you have this testmethod:

```
@IsTest
private class NewSysadTest {
  @IsTest
  static void testSuccess() {
    User testUser =   new User(
        username=UserInfo.getUserId()+'.'+ (DateTime.now()+':'+Math.random()).HashCode()+
                 '@'+UserInfo.getOrganizationId()+'.sfdcOrg',
        alias = 'testExec',
        email='apextests@example.com',
        emailencodingkey='UTF-8',
        lastname='Testing',
        languagelocalekey='en_US',
        localesidkey='en_US',
        profileId = [SELECT Id FROM Profile WHERE Name = 'System Administrator'].Id,
        timezonesidkey='America/Los_Angeles'
    );
    insert testUser;
    PermissionSetAssignment psa = new PermissionSetAssignment(
        AssigneeId = testUser.Id,
        PermissionSetId = [SELECT Id FROM PermissionSet 
                             WHERE Name = 'somePermissionSetName'][0].Id);
    insert psa;  // gack here
  }
}
```

- In Spring 22, you will get a GACK `25028890-5216755 (324258501) (324258501)` on the insert of the `PermissionSetAssignment`; GACK occurs as well if wrapped in `System.runAs`
- In Winter 22, it runs fine

**Case filed with SFDC Support**

Comment: Have you tried runAs

Comment: @identigral good suggestion -- however same error with runAs

Comment: are you able to share the gack id?

Comment: @KrisGoncalves GACK added to OP; I thought only SFDC Support could make use of those ??

Comment: Public reference can't hurt.

Comment: dev internal folks can search with it as well to find linked work/known issues so you never know if someone will do so. Otherwise, it might help someone find this post. Speaking of which, if you need to unblock yourself - it seems setting `UserPermissionsKnowledgeUser = true` for the user should allow the test to pass. I could have this wrong, but It seems to be throwing an access error on a specific knowledge permission on the permissionset. Support can hopefully get more action/info on what's going on and what the best course of action is (need a patch, org permission, etc).

Comment: @KrisGoncalves- thanks - please add an answer (how did you figure this out??). The error occurs on `fflib_SecurityUtilsTest` which runs daily and invokes a custom Flow that assigns PS to new sysads as part of one of my sandbox's Gearset UnitTests - the OP is a MVR of that fflib testmethod + flow

Comment: I'm glad you had a MVR as I was easily able to reproduce it (and see it pass afterwards). I'm internal now (so no magical powers), but I can see a bit more behind the scenes with these types of issues. Support can get back to you on a more official response - there could be more at play happening.

Comment: @cropredy Can you also share the Case number please.

Comment: I see case number @cropredy logged is #41891331.Will keep an eye on the case.  This issue was reported by several other customers too and we have a bug logged for it internally #W-10419259 and Inv #W-10414023. Will keep you posted on the progress

Comment: @cropredy thanks for raising this issue, we have similar-ish issue.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

*Fixed* - This will be handled by Spring '22 Patch 4.6.

---

*Update*: There is now a Known Issue - [Test classes are failing with Salesforce Internal Server Error](https://trailblazer.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p4V000001bH6aQAE). The workaround listed is to update the versions of the classes to 54.

---

*I work for Salesforce, not on the team related to this, so the below is only based on my analysis of what I see based on the stacktrace/gack).*

For now, you can add the Knowledge permission to the User in your test to avoid hitting the error (so your builds/checks will pass).

```
User testUser = new User(...,
UserPermissionsKnowledgeUser = true,
...
```

Internally, the gack/stacktrace is related to not finding/existing a permission (specifically, related to Knowledge) when looking at the permissions on the `PermissionSet`. As that's not something under your control, I *presume* it shouldn't be doing this (considering it passed previously). The workaround above gets around that since the User will have access to Knowledge and thus that permission is exposed/available to be queried/checked.

Support will be able to get a concrete answer and a course of action on what will/should happen. Again, this is not official, but I would venture a *guess* a patch will fix this so you do not need the workaround above.